# Check all checkboxes when main checkbox is checked and vice-versa in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have created many checkboxes in asp.net using vb.net programmatically
I want to check all the checkboxes when main checkbox is checked. 
Main checkbox is created in page_Load event.
But its CheckChanged event is not firing

Comment: Maybe you didn't set the AutoPostBack property of CheckBox to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` to your checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_checkedChanged"/>
```